# Getting error while trying to load laravel project

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, laravel

I am getting error on `master.blade.php` file in views folder.

the error message is :

```
*<br/>ParseError <br/>syntax error, unexpected '{', expecting ')' (View: E:\soft\Xampp2\htdocs\Royaltyexoticcars\resources\views\frontView\master.blade.php)*
```

The responsible 96th(shown in error message) line of code is

```
<script
    type="text/javascript">window.__WEBFLOW_CURRENCY_SETTINGS = { 
        "currencyCode": "USD", 
        "$init": true, 
        "symbol": "$", 
        "decimal": ".", 
        "fractionDigits": 2, 
        "group": ",", 
        "template": "{{wf {\"path\":\"symbol\",\"type\":\"PlainText\"} }} {{wf {\"path\":\"amount\",\"type\":\"CommercePrice\"} }} {{wf {\"path\":\"currencyCode\",\"type\":\"PlainText\"} }}", 
        "hideDecimalForWholeNumbers": false };
</script>
```

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think here's your problem:

```
"template": "{{wf {\"path\":\"symbol\",\"type\":\"PlainText\"} }} {{wf {\"path\":\"amount\",\"type\":\"CommercePrice\"} }} {{wf {\"path\":\"currencyCode\",\"type\":\"PlainText\"} }}",
```

Blade probably tries to execute that line of code, if you don't want that prepend an @ symbol like this (also this doesn't have to be that messy I guess):

```
template: "@{{wf {\"path\":\"symbol\",\"type\":\"PlainText\"} }} @{{wf {\"path\":\"amount\",\"type\":\"CommercePrice\"} }} @{{wf {\"path\":\"currencyCode\",\"type\":\"PlainText\"} }}",
```

Comment: well there are a couple of occurences of curly braces. You need to escape every one of them, see updated answer. Which templating language is this?

Comment: Thanks for helping me. I really appreciate it. as I am not able to give upvote yet, I couldnt able to give you upvote. But I promise , as soon as I am given the ability to upvote I will upvote your answer.

Comment: No problemo, I think you can accept it though, if you want ;)

Answer (score 0):

use need to use `@` symbol  before `{{` to  inform the Blade rendering engine an expression should remain untouched.

more info read [Blade & JavaScript Frameworks](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/blade#blade-and-javascript-frameworks)